# why i can't get my text from kivy TextInput?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

well I'm entirely new to kivy, it's a bit complicated but I'm trying to get on

so I'm stuck on something, I'm trying to get a text from a `TextInput`, but i can't, it just refuse to do it, can anyone crack it?

KV code:

```
<Signin>:
    
    title:"Telegram Checker"
    AnchorLayout:
        
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'

        BoxLayout:
            
            width : 600
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            
            Label:
                
                text:"Telegram Sign-In"
                
            TextInput:
                id : tel
                input_type:'tel'
                width:600
                multiline: False
                hint_text: '+XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                size_hint: None, None
                height: 50
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 20
            spacing: 100
            width : 600
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            
            Button:
                text: "Next ->"
                #size_hint: 0.5,6
                height : 100
                pos:self.pos
                on_release : app.send_code_request()
```

the function that's not getting the text :

```
class MyApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        self.title="Telegram Checker"
        return screen_manager
    
    def send_code_request(self):
        phone = self.root.ids.tel.text
        print(phone)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74755977/2397865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code at the bottom is runnable and it passes the argument you requested.  It shows this being done two ways.  I suggest not using the .ids property because you can link the items at the top of the .kv class and assign type hints to the object like this:

```
tel: TextInput
```

full code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<Signin>:
    # match the python object to the kivy id
    # python on the left: kivy id on the right
    tel: tel

    title:"Telegram Checker"
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        BoxLayout:
            width : 600
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            Label:
                text:"Telegram Sign-In"
            TextInput:
                id : tel
                input_type:'tel'
                width:600
                multiline: False
                hint_text: '+XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                size_hint: None, None
                height: 50
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 20
            spacing: 100
            width : 600
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: None, None
            Button:
                text: "Next ->"
                #size_hint: 0.5,6
                height : 100
                pos:self.pos
                on_release : app.send_code_request(tel.text, self)
'''
)


class Signin(Screen):
    # python objects mapped in the .kv file.  this is a type hint which will help with auto-complete
    tel: TextInput

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(f" hint text is {self.tel.hint_text}")


class MyApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_top_widget = ScreenManager()
        self.signin_screen = Signin(name="sign_in")

    def send_code_request(self, phone: str, your_button, *args) -> None:

        # this is one way
        print(f" by id {self.signin_screen.ids.tel.text}")

        print(f"vale passed={phone} \nyour button {your_button} other args {args}")

    def build(self):

        self.title = "Telegram Checker"

        self.my_top_widget.add_widget(self.signin_screen, name="sign_in")
        self.my_top_widget.current = "sign_in"
        return self.my_top_widget


my_app = MyApp()
my_app.run()
```