# How to reference a .kv page inside python

Tags: python, button, kivy

how can I code a function in python which opens the next window in a .kv file?

Since the buttons are created dynamically I want to add the button function (to go to the next page) inside the python code. I just do not get how to "reference" the page from the .kv file in my python code.

So the python function should do the same as:

```
Button: 
        size_hint_y: .05
        size_hint_x: .25
        background_color: 0,0,0,0
        pos_hint:{"center_y":0.04, "x": 0.71}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'EditPage'  <------
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74755977/2397865
that answer has general information about linking.  but I think you are specifically looking for ScreenManager.  look up the documentation about that.  it is relatively advanced so my advice is to make sure you can do simple things first, connecting the id in Kivy files to specific objects in the python code.