# Is there a way to disable kivy button with an external condition?

Tags: python, button, kivy

I'm trying to build a program that takes a physical input and do some stuff(obj and motors) and while those two function are executing I need to disable a button. I tried something like this but nothing happens. Is there a way to enable/disable a button with a python function? Thanks in advance.

```
async def action():
    await MainMenu.disable()
    await obj()
    motors()
    print('action is finished, starting loop agian')
    await MainMenu.enable()
```

```
class MainMenu(Screen):
    running = BooleanProperty(False)
    
    async def disable():
        running = BooleanProperty(True)
        return running
    
    async def enable():
        running  = BooleanProperty(False)
        return running 
    pass
```

kv file

```
<MainMenu>:
    Button:
        text: 'button that needs to be disabled'
        disabled: root.running
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74755977/2397865   see that answer regarding 'my_button'.  you need to assign an id and then do some work to link that id in the kivy file over to the Python file.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning values to the `running` Property correctly. In your methods, just do something like:

```
self.running = True
```

or

```
self.running = False
```

This code should work:

```
class MainMenu(Screen):
    running = BooleanProperty(False)

    def disable(self):
        self.running = True

    def enable(self):
        self.running = False
```

Comment: First thanks for the quick reply, so changing the method to self.running gives me the error cannot create graphics instructions outside the main kivy thread. Given that I cannot put the @mainthread decorator on the action function how can that variable be changed from a function outside the main kivy thread(in general I don't understand how to connect python code and kivy)? Sorry, I am a noob in both python and kivy. :|

Comment: Please post a [mcve].